# PHP - Converting XML/RDF into HTML

Tags: php, html, xml, rdf

On this URL:
http://www.ontobee.org/ontology/HP?iri=http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/HP_0001065

When I inspect elements with Chrome, I can see the HTML:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="mainbody">
      <link href="http://www.ontobee.org/public/css/ontology.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="http://www.ontobee.org/public/js/ontobee.ontology.js"></script>
      <h3 class="title">
        <a href="http://www.ontobee.org/ontology/HP"> human phenotype ontology</a>
      </h3>
      <form action="http://www.ontobee.org/search" method="get" id="keyword-search">
        <input name="ontology" id="ontology" type="hidden" value="HP" />
        <div class="ui-widget">
          <strong>
            <label for="keywords">Keywords: </label>
          </strong>
          <input id="keywords" name="keywords" size="30" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search terms" />
        </div>
      </form>
      <p class="section-title">
  Class: <span class="section-title-value">Striae distensae</span></p>
      <div class="iri">...
```

I see the HTML but when I view the source, I get XML:

```
    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Annotation properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->

    <AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasRelatedSynonym"/>
    <AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000115"/>
    <AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasDbXref"/>
    <AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#inSubset"/>
    <AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasAlternativeId"/>
    <AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasOBONamespace"/>
```

I need a way to convert the RDF/XML into HTML programatically. Is there simple way to do this? Do I need to find their XML transform file?

NOTE: The reason I need to do this is because I need to download a batch of these documents. I need to scrape the data. They have a SPARQ API, but I already wrote a scraper thinking that what I was looking at was a HTML document, I rarely just write something from beginning to end without testing it as I go along, but some reason this time I did. There must be a way to do it through a browser plugin since the browser is able to output the HTML.

Comment: Let me get this straight: you're getting back data in a machine-processable, structured format (RDF/XML), but you want it transformed to a human-readable format (HTML), so that you can then... _scrape_ it to turn it back into something structured/machine-processable?

I understand that you already started on this before you realized your mistake, but even so it might _still_ be more efficient (and certainly better in the long run) to just abandon your scraper and write a simple RDF-processing client instead.

Comment: Yeah I got a bit ahead of myself and wrote the whole script, every detail of it before testing it. Usually I'd test things as I go along. You're right, I should just abandon the script. Parsing the XML should be relatively easy.

Comment: That'll work, but using an actual RDF library, like EasyRDF, might be even easier. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks. That'll probably save me a lot of hassle when I get around to doing this. I really know anything about RDF.

Answer (score 1):

The RDF on the page is for the class being displayed. So,no, you could not engineer the HTML of the page from the RDF.

If you're looking for the HTML of the page itself, its easier for you to get the HTML from the inspect tool of the browser.

Comment: The issue is I need to get a bulk quantity of these pages. Maybe theres a chrome or firefox plugin that will let me download batches of HTML for a list of pages.